# How to model an association with a transitive dependency?

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-relationship

I am lost at modeling an association with a transitive dependency. Here is the corresponding ERM:

[image: ERM]

A match has one home team and one guest team (let's stick to the home team for simplicity). I would therefore include a team_id attribute in the match.

**Now, how can I make sure that the team maintained in the match participates in the match's league?** I'm open to introducing join tables, but do not see how to keep the information about the transitive dependency "team -> *plays in* -> match -> *being part of* -> league -> *with participating* -> team"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming *both* teams have to be in the match's league. The solution involves overlapping constraints and overlapping foreign key references.

You show a m:n relationship between teams and leagues. Matches will reference this table.

```
create table team_leagues (
  team_id ...,
  league_id ...,
  other_columns ...,
  primary key (team_id, league_id),
  foreign key (team_id) references teams (team_id),
  foreign key (league_id) references leagues (league_id)
);
```

And there's a 1:n relationship between leagues and matches. There are overlapping constraints here.

```
create table matches (
  home_team_id ..., 
  guest_team_id ...,
  match_start_time ...,
  league_id ...,
  primary key (home_team_id, match_start_time),
  unique (guest_team_id, match_start_time),
  foreign key (home_team_id, league_id) 
    references team_leagues (team_id, league_id),
  foreign key (guest_team_id, league_id)
    references team_leagues (team_id, league_id)
);
```

Whether matches.league_id also needs a foreign key reference to leagues is application-dependent. I *think* it should be sufficient to reference team_leagues, though.

Comment: I was so locked up in the Ruby on Rails world, which does not support foreign keys so well, that I didn't even think about using foreign key constraints. Thanks a lot - greatly appreciated.